# how can I convert my c# object to json and save in realm db as string?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

Below is the object I am trying to save in Realm DB where Student will be RealmObject. I want MyCustomObj member in the below model to be saved as a JSON object and also an OList member in below model to be saved as an array of objects.

```
public class Student:RealmObject
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        [PrimaryKey]

        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public MyCustomObj MyCustomObj { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public IList<OptionItems> OList { get;  }
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought of using NewtonSoft.Json?

Comment: @FreakyAli seems like he is already using that looking at the JsonProperty attributes he  is showing.

Comment: @FreakyAli I am using NewtonSoft.Json

Comment: Yeah I know you are using it, what I meant was using it for deserializing!!

Comment: @FreakyAli Sorry, I have modified the question. I just want to save the object in the realm DB as JSON string.